# Apache - Image loads hangs the same time as KeepAliveTimeout value

Tags: apache, keep-alive

I have a strange problem with Apache. Most of the time it works fine. But about 1 out of 10 times, one or two images hangs for exact same time as value specified as KeepAliveTimeout in Apache. Those hanging images load fine, right after the KeepAliveTimeout time.

Can someone explain me why this is happening ? And how can I avoid it ?

I am using Apache 2.4.6, prefork mpm, and relevant lines from my config are:

```
StartServers 10
MinSpareServers 40
MaxSpareServers 100
MaxClients 250
MaxRequestsPerChild 0
Timeout 30
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100000
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```